# Role of Docker in CI/CD?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am a newbie to CI/CD and was trying to understand why exactly do we need docker in CI/CD.

Since the CI server will compile test and build the apk and through shell scripts this apk would be pushed to HockeyApp to their respective environment buckets.So where exactly and why is docker needed in the whole process?

Comment: At the [Docker website](https://www.docker.com/use-cases/cicd), you can see some use cases about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can go through https://www.docker.com/use-cases/cicd.

As per my knowledge through Docker, you can achieve 2 major things
1. The same environment to run an application i.e. a lightweight virtualization.
2. Easier distribution, as Docker is based on layer architecture.

For Development, you can build your solution on microservice architecture

For CI, it would be easier to replicate the same environment in multiple machine/same machine where tests can be executed parallelly.

For CD, easier to deploy the changes on production also it will provide the same environment for an application in production as in development which will resolve issues of "it works on my machine but not in production".

You can also go through Docker swarm which will help you in Blue/Green deployment
https://technologyconversations.com/2017/01/31/blue-green-deployments-with-docker-services-running-inside-a-swarm-cluster/

Answer (score 1):

In your CI/CD pipeline you might require build tools like maven, or any other required softwares like sshpass,jq, ansible etc. So instead of installing all the required softwares at run time, you can have these in a docker image and you can use them.

Example(.gitlab-ci.yml):

```
build:
 stage: build
 image: $DOCKER_REGISTRY/maven/v3.5

script:
 - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile
```